# C# Source Generators: conditionally generate code via command line properties or pre-processor define constants

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I am writing a source generator using the incremental generator approach.

I want to allow the developers to be able to conditionally generate some extra code (e.g. extra comments, debug printouts, pedantic validations in the generated code, etc.) and I would like this to be controlled by either:

- `DefineConstants` by adding the following to the `.csproj` file of the project using my source generator:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MY_PROJECT_EXTRA</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

- or via the `-p:` option on the `dotnet build` command line:

```
dotnet build ProjectUsingMySourceGeneratorCode.csproj -p:MyProjectExtra=true
```

I checked the following types I have access to: `IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext`, `SourceProductionContext`, `Compilation` but could not find anything.

As workaround I could add a custom attribute that developers can use to decorate the syntax elements they want to control, but this might require developers to add the attribute many classes/methods manually.

Is there a way I can access either (or both) `DefineConstants` or command line `-p:` properties (or any other compile-time settings) inside the `IncrementalGenerator` workflow?

Comment: See the docs: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#consume-msbuild-properties-and-metadata

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comment from @caton7 I was able to find a way an initial solution using `.editorconfig`. I think incremental generators might work slightly different than original source generators so I ended up doing something similar to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#access-analyzer-config-properties.

**My solution**

*.editorconfig*

```
myvalue = foo
```

*SourceGenerator.cs*

```
public class SourceGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator {
   public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
   {
       // Step 1. Identify the classes.
       var classDeclarations = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(
                static (node, ct) => true /* Update with your code */,
                static (context, ct) => context.Node as ClassDeclarationSyntax /* Update with your code*/)
            .Where(CommonExtensions.IsNotNull);

       // Step 2. Combine analyser, compilation and class declaration
       var analizerConfigOptionsCompilationAndClasses = context
            .AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider
            .Combine(context
                .CompilationProvider
                .Combine(classDeclarations.Collect()));

       // Step 3. Register the source output to generate the code.
       context.RegisterSourceOutput(
            analizerConfigOptionsCompilationAndClasses,
            static (context, settings) => Execute(context, settings.Left, settings.Right.Left, settings.Right.Right));
    }

   private static Execute(SourceProductionContext context, AnalyzerConfigOptionsProvider analyzerConfigOptionsProvider, Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray<ClassDeclarationSyntax?> classDeclarationSyntaxes))
   {
      // NOTE: Unsure why by analyzerConfigOptionsProvider.TryGetValue("myvalue", out var x) would never return the values I would be expecting.

      foreach (var classDeclarationSyntax in classDeclarationSyntaxes)
      {
         if (classDeclarationSyntax is null)
         {
            continue;
         }

         var options = analyzerConfigOptionsProvider.GetOptions(classDeclarationSyntax.SyntaxTree);
         options.TryGetValue("myvalue", out string? myvalue);
         /* myvalue should now be equal to the string foo as defined in .editorconfig */
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can also use MSBuild properties as your question asked, just see slightly further down in that doc

Comment: @canton7 I tried that following your comment on the original post but I was unsuccessful: I setup my generator project to generate a NuGet package, added the .props, updated my generator .csproj (and make sure the .nuget contained the expected files) but nothing. To be honest I am not sure if it is because I am using incremental generators or because I missed something in the generation/setup of the package.